# Jquery access elements under li tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to access and modify elements under **li**.

Basically I want to access **a** tag by accessing **li**

HTML :

```
<ul>
   <li data-id="1">
     <a href="#">Data 1</a>
   </li>
   <li data-id="2">
     <a href="#">Data 2</a>
   </li>
<ul/>
```

js

```
var number = '1';
var my_li = $('li[data-id="' + number + '"]');
my_li.a.css('color', 'red')   // i want to change color of anchor tag.
```

Comment: Why do you need to access the `a` through the `li`, can't you just `.find()` inside it?

Comment: no list (li) is dynamic

Comment: You can just use `my_li.children().css('color', 'red') `, if you want to update the color of all the child elements inside the li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose either ways to do this

```
 $('li[data-id="' + number + '"] a').css('color', 'red');

 $('li[data-id="' + number + '"]').children('a').css('color', 'red');

 var my_li = $('li[data-id="' + number + '"]');
 my_li.children('a').css('color', 'red')
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://api.jquery.com/children/), you can use `$(selector).children(filter)`

```
var my_li = $('li[data-id="' + number + '"]').children().css({"color": "red"});
```

**Update**
Here the working fiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul").children().css({"color": "red"});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.descendants * { 
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="descendants">body (great-grandparent)
  <div style="width:500px;">div (grandparent)
    <ul>ul (direct parent)  
      <li>li (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </li>
      <li>li (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try this one:

```
$("a", my_li).css({color: 'red'});
```